# Distance between two cities at equal latitudes

Tags: distance, latitude-longitude

NY is at 41 lat and -74 longitude. 
Barcelona is at 41 lat and 2 lon.

If I were to travel along 41 degrees latitude (NOT the shortest path). How many kilometers would I travel? Assume R = 6378KM.

Comment: Have a read of https://community.esri.com/groups/coordinate-reference-systems/blog/2014/09/01/geodetic-distances-how-long-is-that-line-again about geodesic distance.. what software are you using? Are you travelling at sea level or cruising attitude?

Comment: As a remark, your longitudes were switched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you assume R = 6378 km, you assume that the Earth is a sphere.

In this case, the size of a parallel is the size of the equator times the cosinus of the latitude.

Then you need a portion of this parallel, so (under your assumptions)

```
equator = 2*pi*R

parallel 41° = (2* pi * R) * cos(41°)

distance = (2* pi * R) * cos(41°) * (2° - (-74°)) /360° = 6385 km
```

To be exact, you should however take into account the flattening of the Earth.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate geographic distance between points on earth using haversine formula.
If performance is an issue and accuracy less important, for small distances Pythagoras’ theorem can be used on an equi­rectangular projec­tion:*

```
Formula 
x = Δλ ⋅ cos φm
y = Δφ
d = R ⋅ √x² + y²

JavaScript: 
var x = (λ2-λ1) * Math.cos((φ1+φ2)/2);
var y = (φ2-φ1);
var d = Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y) * R;

Haversine
formula:    a = sin²(Δφ/2) + cos φ1 ⋅ cos φ2 ⋅ sin²(Δλ/2)
                c = 2 ⋅ atan2( √a, √(1−a) )
                d = R ⋅ c
```

Follow the link for more detailed approach. https://www.igismap.com/haversine-formula-calculate-geographic-distance-earth/